# How to override x-editable ajax response value?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using x-editable to do inline editing. When I update the value via ajax and x-editable to get the response, I am finding it very difficult to override the div that contains the new x-editable value.

For example, my x-editable link looks like this:

```
 <a href="#" id="freight">$100</a>
```

I enter my edit in the pop-up that x-editable provides then enter the value 300.00

When I do my edits, I proceed as follows:

```
 $('#freight').editable({
            validate: function(value) {
                if($.trim(value) == '') return 'This value is required.';
            },
            type: 'text',
            url: '{{ path('update_purchase_order_ajax') }}',
            pk: {{ purchaseOrder.id }},
            title: 'Enter Freight Value',
            ajaxOptions: {
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            success: function(response, newValue) {
                // Update the purchase order amounts...
                $('#freight').html('$' + newValue);
            }
        });
```

When x-editable is finished, the value that shows up on the page is now 300.00 (without the $ dollar sign). As you can see in my jquery code, I am trying to override the value x-editable is putting on the page with $('#freight').html('$' + newValue);

For some reason this is not working. I want $300.00 to show up, not 300.00.

Comment: shouldnt you put \$ . this is a little bit confusing to me

Answer (score 12):

What you need to do is prevent the `display` method from overwriting your `success` method.

```
display: function(value, response) {
  return false;   //disable this method
},
success: function(response, newValue) {
  $(this).html('$' + newValue);
}
```

On the server side, your JSON should be like this, `{newValue : <value>}`

Answer (score 4):

As long as your response is of the format:

```
{"success":true,"pk":2311,"newValue":"somenewvalue"}
```

**and** you make sure to return the response from the success callback:

```
success: function(response) {
   var newValue = '$'+response.newValue;
   response.newValue = newValue;
   return response;
}
```

then x-editable should update the field for you.  Just remember to include `success`, `pk`, and `newValue` keys in the response.

Answer (score 3):

x-editable has a option "display:function(value, response){}" that can be used to modify the data that appears on the page:

```
 ,
 display: function(value, response) {
      $(this).text(response.new_value);
      // new_value being the value that is returned via the json response...
      // this value can either be modified here in the javascript or in the controller which set the value...
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

Following are two cases

**Case 1**: you want to just display value differently

you can use render event

```
$('#action').on('render', function(e, editable) {
    var colors = {0: "gray", 1: "green", 2: "blue", 3: "red"};
    $(this).css("color", colors[editable.value]); 
});
```

**Case 2**: you want to set value to element which is returned in ajax response instead of what set at client side e.g. uesr inserted value "Hello" but sever converts it into "hello"(small case) then do following

in ajax response set new value e.g. `{"success":true,"pk":13,"value":"hello"}`

use following code

```
success:function(data, config) {
    if(typeof(data) == 'object'){
        var api_id = data.pk;
        var success = data.success;
        if(success == true){
            return {newValue:data.value}
        }   
    }
}
```

ensure you return object with exact name **newValue**

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(response, newValue) {
  // Update the purchase order amounts...
  $('#freight').editable('option', 'value', newValue);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.