# Split a value in PHP apart from explode

Tags: php

How I can split this value in the form of city, street and building? Apart from the `explode` function.

```
value = { city: "Indore", street: "dd102, 302-raj palace, Indrapuri", building: "dd" }
```

This is not json, this is normal ajax.

How do i convert this to Json? Here is my javascript looks like:

```
$('#address').editable({
            url: redirecturl,
            value: {
                city: "<?php echo $EditUserDetails->city; ?>",
                street: "<?php echo $EditUserDetails->address; ?>"

            },
            validate: function (value) {
                if (value.city == '') return 'city is required!';
            },
            display: function (value) {
                if (!value) {
                    $(this).empty();
                    return;
                }
                var html = '<b>' + $('<div>').text(value.city).html() + '</b>, ' + $('<div>').text(value.street).html() + ', ' + $('<div>').text(value.building).html();
                $(this).html(html);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If it's json, use `json_decode`

Comment: Its not JSON but close for json_decode to handle it keys would have to be encapsulated in "'s like { "city": "Indore", "street": "dd102, 302-raj palace, Indrapuri", "building": "dd" } for the data the poster supllied json_decode will return false.

Comment: i think we need more code to examine...

Comment: so it's something just like json, but broken?

Comment: Also, is it clear if the `value = ` bit is part of the string the OP is parsing? Otherwise, the whole string could be misrepresented

Comment: There is no such thing as "normal ajax". ajax is a data transfer method, not a data format.

Comment: do you have control over how the data is sent over? If so, why not .... make it json?

Comment: you should transform it to json format $value = '{ "city": "Indore", "street": "dd102, 302-raj palace, Indrapuri", "building": "dd" }';

Comment: Yes this is the whole string sent when i post the ajax value.

Comment: Do you have any control over how the string is formatted before it's sent? Are you using a js library to handle it? if so, which one?

Comment: you can see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025483/how-to-over-ride-x-editable-ajax-response-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$value = '{ city: "Indore", street: "dd102, 302-raj palace, Indrapuri", building: "dd" }';

$value = trim(str_replace("\",", "\";", $value), "{}");
$array = explode(";", $value);
$object = array();

foreach ($array as $item)
{
    $temp = explode(": ", str_replace('"', '', trim($item)));
    $object[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}

print_r($object);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [city] => Indore 
    [street] => dd102, 302-raj palace, Indrapuri 
    [building] => dd 
)
```

Comment: Will not work. json_decode will return NULL since the keys are not enclosed in "

Comment: i use this and got this error "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Comment: json format is like this: $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

Comment: I think this is the last option i have, i know this explode function. But dont want to use this. :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Corrected the code.
If the result is deliverd in this format:

```
$value = 'value = { city: "Indore", street: "dd102, 302-raj palace, Indrapuri", building: "dd" }';
```

You can use this:

```
$value = 'value = { city: "Indore", street: "dd102, 302-raj palace, Indrapuri", building: "dd" }';
$value = preg_replace('/(\w+):/', '"$1":', $value);
$value = preg_replace('/.*({.*\}).*/', '$1', $value);
$object = json_decode($value);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($object);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your ajax request :

> type:"json"

After that you can used json_decode();

Comment: How can i use type:"json in my JavaScript?"